Android 11 - Format SD as Adoptable storage
I use a device on Android 11, Xiaomi OEM, MIUI 12.5.7
I formatted my SD card as Adoptable storage, though I had to get that "Fix SD card" prompt to select "format as phone's storage" because, in settings, the SD card is formatted as portable by default.
Now here's the thing, after formatting the SD card as added internal storage, I can't find the SD card anymore, there's no option to unmount it in settings, can't find the additional space when I look in the file manager, is this normal?
My device is rooted BTW, any tips are appreciated, my goal is to get more space for my games, I've had little success with Link2sd, strangely the tool was working perfectly for linking game/app data to the first partition of my ext storage before I flashed my phone, now I'm left with no ideas on what to do.

I don't think you understand how adopted storage works... Once added, the phone treats as an extension of the system storage, you can't mount/unmount or do anything with it directly... It's no longer "external storage" it is now part of the system, you don't manage it anymore, the system does.

Does this answer your question? Link2SD - Game ignores binded data after link
